# How to convert the specific String to DateTime Format in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, string-to-datetime

```
String date  = 'July 7,2020 10:00 AM'
```

How can I convert the above string to DateTime Format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String date = 'July 7,2020 10:00 AM';
DateFormat d = DateFormat('MMMM d,yyyy hh:mm a');
print(d.parse(date));
```

For more info : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Thanks Mahesh

DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm().parse(date), I also got this from another forum